# call to connect fails with errno 111 inside a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, tcpsocket

I have a back-end app that i deploy in a Docker container. The app is running just fine, but when I try, from within the app, to open a TCP socket (in order to connect to it with a GUI front-end from the host) by calling [connect](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/connect.html), the call fails with **errno 111**, namely ECONNREFUSED (connection refused).

The requested socket details: `0.0.0.0:50000`

i run the image with: `docker run -p 50000:50000 my_image`

Both the host and the container are running Ubuntu 20.04.

Doing this directly on the host works just fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `0.0.0.0:50000` looks like a correct listen address for a process inside a container, but not something you'd connect to.  What URL are you using in your client code?  What's in the image, and is it in fact listening on that special "all interfaces" address?

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for replying.
i'm using the same URL from the front-end on the host, namely `0.0.0.0:50000`, but this happens regardless of the front-end running or not.
the image has a ROS2 app running on it, which communicates with my back-end via named pipes. my app is run inside the docker via a startup script so it can run as a second process to the ROS2 process. specifically, this is the script line that runs it inside the image:
`nohup ./path/to/executable/my_app -a 0.0.0.0 -p 50000 &`
Not really sure what you mean by "the image listening" on that address.  
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me why, but adding -it to the docker run command fixed it...